# Form of density for non-differentiable transformations

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Consider the transformation $Z = g(Y)$.

Here, $g:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow [0,1]$ is a strictly increasing continuous function that is not necessarily differentiable.

I believe this implies that $Z$ is also absolutely continuous, but
what is an expression for the density of $Z$?